# SQL connection string on Windows Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to connect my C# desktop app on PC 1 with database that exist on SQL server instance at  Windows Server 2008. First I cannot make my connection string works.

My connection string is:

```
Server=(Server_Ip)192.168.1.115\(InstanceName)SQLExpress8;initial
catalog=My_Database;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
```

I also tried:

```
Server=(ServerName)DATABASE\(InstanceName)SQLExpress8;initial
catalog=My_Database;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
```

But that doesn't work.

By the way I have replaced `server` with `datasource` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow, please only keep one problem per question. You're free to ask another question about connecting servers through Internet.

Comment: Hello A. L
Sorry About This Miss 
THanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are putting the parenthesis in your connection string but this is an example of a working one for sql server

```
connectionString="Server=testServer\instanceName; uid=readOnlyUser; pwd=1234567; database=testDatabase" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

where

```
testServer = IP or server name
instanceName = instance name, sometimes SQLExpress for sql server express
testDatabase = database name
uid = user name
pwd = password
```

you CAN connect your windows app to the database, however the server IP has to be public to the internet, you will have to mess with firewall settings in order to do that to allow the IP to be accessed publicly.

Comment: Hello Eliseo  Thanks For Your Answer 
i log in into my sql server with windows authorization So Is this Wok Or must Log In With sql server authentication ??

Comment: Here Is my Real Code In App.config
     <connectionStrings><add name="Gimatex_Clothes_Factory_DBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entity.Entity_For_Gimatex_Clothes_Factory.csdl|res://*/Entity.Entity_For_Gimatex_Clothes_Factory.ssdl|res://*/Entity.Entity_For_Gimatex_Clothes_Factory.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;
    Server=192.168.1.115\SQL8;initial catalog=Gimatex_Clothes_Factory_DB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Hey 
i undrstand the connection string and what is contain but i think 
 there is  some thing i must do in windows server to allow my app connecting with database ?
by the way i can make remote connection with server without any problems

Comment: If the application is local is being tested locally (on the same server as the database) and you are able to use sql server management studio and connect to the database the problem is probably in your application. Step through the application line by line in debug mode, you might have another issue. For server use localhost or 127.0.0.1 to see if that helps any.